# RecyclerView starts behind default TitleBar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

Requirement is to have a RecylerView between TitleBar and BottomNavigationView. However, the RecyclerView starts from behind the TitleBar.
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/hs_clayout"
    tools:context="com.sd.snafis.cards.HomeScreen" >


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3S]

As you can see, the first card comes below the TitleBar. I tried setting marginTop to the RecyclerView, but it does not work. Would prefer the solution to use ConstraintLayout, instead of changing layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

or `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`

in xml for `RecyclerView`

Comment: `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"`
This works but not sure why. Shouldn't any view start below the TitleBar.?

Comment: Both should work , as per my understanding. As it worked I have updated my answer with your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set `<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>`in your activity theme? if it set, you can remove it or set it's value to false.

you can  add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`in ConstraintLayout Whether or not `windowActionBarOverlay` is set to true.

Comment: No, I have not set this item. Adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` did not work.